# VBA Download Image URL that contains Hebrew

Tags: excel, vba, image, url, hebrew

I have a link that contains Hebrew in the file name: [http://erezshaked.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/תפוח.jpg](http://erezshaked.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%97.jpg)

I am trying to download it but it doesn't let me. I'm basically trying to encode the slug in it to make it:
http://erezshaked.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%97.jpg

So I will be able to download it.

I already have a code that downloads image from URL but it doesn't work when there's Hebrew on the URL. this is the code I have:

```
Sub Download_Image()

    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    URLDownloadToFile 0, Cells(2, 1).Value, "E:\temp\" & Cells(2, 2) & ".jpg", 0, 0
        
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("E:\temp\")
    Set objFile = objFolder.ParseName(Cells(2, 2) & ".jpg")

End Sub
```

And this is the content of the worksheet:
[image]
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: "It doesn't work"? What is the error message?
Also, variable i is not initialized.

Comment: i was not initialized because I took all the loop and other stuff out for the sake of this test. I fixed it you can check now.

Comment: Check my working answer below. It's impossible to test your code because the content of the worksheet  is unknown. Also you should have Cells(2, 2).Value

Comment: I've added the content of my worksheet also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with cell A1 set to [http://erezshaked.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/תפוח.jpg](http://erezshaked.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%97.jpg):

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
Sub Download_Image()

    Dim url As String
    Dim enc As String
    
    url = Range("A1").Value
          
    enc = WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(url)
    enc = Replace(enc, "%3A", ":")
    enc = Replace(enc, "%2F", "/")
    URLDownloadToFile 0, enc, "E:\temp\test.jpg", 0, 0
End Sub
```

Comment: http://erezshaked.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%97.jpg    is without Hebrew, the Hebrew turned into decoded URL

I need to download the second link: http://erezshaked.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/תפוח.jpg

Comment: Ok, now I added the required encode function.

Comment: The first and last arguments of `URLDownloadToFileA` are `LongPtr`s.

Comment: it doesn't work, you encoded the whole cell and only the last part should have been encoded, I actually made it work by stripping only the filename (everything after the last "/") and then encoding it. and then downloading the fixed URL: everything before the last "/" + encoded everything after the last "/".

Comment: Well, this is not a programming service. I solved the encode problem for you so you should be a gentleman and mark my answer.